# WKWebView process termination

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView in an application and sometimes I get a blank screen because the process dealing with content crashes.

WKNavigationDelegate has a `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:` method and I implemented it in my view controller.

I can see the memory growth of the webkit process in Instruments but whenever the screen goes blank the methods never gets called.
Other methods of the delegate are working correctly.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

well, webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate delegate can be called if process terminates. However, it is not called once the screen goes blank. There is a delay.